# Google+ Javascript origin_mismatch

Tags: google-plus

It's been a long day and this problem is going to kill me, I've been trying everything out, every single google search with no luck... Okay, the problem is that whenever I try to log in to my website using google+ it gives me an error: "Error: origin_mismatch". I know that the problem is in my google+ credentials but it looks perfect to me... when I go to my google+ project -> credentials and I can find my javascript origins which are set to: http://diligencehelps.com, yes I have tried http://www.diligencehelps.com, and no,I don't have ssl certificate so it's 100% not https.
The button html code:

```
<span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="280481825574-ba84rmjmt5emvhn95k7d6kdkc68rcbjg.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
</span>
```

Comment: Clicking on the G+ sign in button on http://www.diligencehelps.com/lesson.php?id=6 I don't get an error.

Comment: Strange, but it fixed itself overnight... I have no idea what happened I have worked on it for sooooo long and the error...just vanished.... Such a good feeling!